# Kendo ui grid not being initialized in IE 11 with compatibility mode enabled

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am running into a problem where I have a pretty simple kendo ui grid that gets updated via ajax calls via a datasource.  I am running it on an intranet so compatibility mode gets enabled.  When I turn compatibility mode off in IE 11 everything works fine, however I'm not sure if I want to do that across all users for all pages in case it would affect other things.  Has anyone else seen this and is there a workaround?

Comment: What about just adding the meta tag for the particular page.  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Comment: This worked thank you.  Saw something about that but couldn't find it again.

Comment: What to do if it makes compatible with all IE varsion, or IE 9 ?